# Is there a way to ignore redefinition with clang?

Tags: c++, clang, redefinition

I am getting a Clang compiler error when compiling ROOT script:

~/root_install/include/ROOT/RStringView.hxx:32:4: **error:** redefinition of 'basic_string_view' as different kind of symbol using basic_string_view = ::std::experimental::basic_string_view<_CharT,_Traits>;
/usr/include/c++/9/string_view:90:11: **note:** previous definition is here
class basic_string_view

This is the problematic code in ROOT library:

```
namespace std {

   template<class _CharT, class _Traits = std::char_traits<_CharT> >
   using basic_string_view = ::std::experimental::basic_string_view<_CharT,_Traits>;

   // basic_string_view typedef names
   typedef basic_string_view<char> string_view;
   typedef basic_string_view<char16_t> u16string_view;
   typedef basic_string_view<char32_t> u32string_view;
   typedef basic_string_view<wchar_t> wstring_view;

//   template<class _CharT, class _Traits = std::char_traits<_CharT> >
//   basic_string_view<_CharT,_Traits>
//   &operator=(basic_string_view<_CharT,_Traits> &lhs, const TString &rsh) {
//      *lhs = basic_string_view<_CharT,_Traits>(rsh);
//      return *lhs;
//   }

#ifndef R__HAS_STOD_STRING_VIEW
   inline double stod(std::string_view str, size_t *pos)
   {
      return std::stod(std::string(str.data(), str.size()),pos);
   }
#endif

}
```

Is there a way to avoid this error without changing the library? Compiling it with g++ with following command works just fine:\

g++ -std=c++2a file.cpp `root-config --cflags --libs`

**Edit:**
Clang compile command:
`clang -std=c++20 --include-directory ~/root_install/include file.cpp`

Comment: Looks like the code is `using` two different basic_string_view.  That won't work.

Comment: You say you compile it with clang, yet you do not post the compile command. That way it is hard to help you. [root-stl-backports](https://root.cern/install/build_from_source/#root-stl-backports) should interest you.

Comment: Why are you using different options for `clang`? (And why aren't you using `clang++`?)

Comment: @molbdnilo I didn't know about `clang++`, but it throws the same error.

Comment: @molbdnilo The error seems to be connected to the newer standard of c++. I would still like to fix it though, in case I will want to use some of the new features.

Comment: `#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /home/user/root_install/include` Why does it only search for <...>?

Comment: The error is connected to your not using the correct options. Have you tried using the `root-config` thing with clang?

Comment: @molbdnilo Yeah, that was the problem. These options did not work before with `clang` but work with `clang++`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ROOT can be compiled with `clang++` (but not with `clang`) using the following command:

clang++ file.C `root-config --cflags --libs`

This also works with the `-std=c++20` flag.